# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'com.sportswin.soa.spark.controller.ISparkGameUserController' method

Tags: java, spring-boot

Today when I start the spring boot project, shows error like this:

```
2022-01-21 14:52:04.659 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webMvcRequestHandlerProvider' defined in URL [jar:file:/root/soa-spark-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/springfox-spring-webmvc-3.0.0.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'com.sportswin.soa.spark.controller.ISparkGameUserController' method 
public abstract com.sportswin.soa.misc.contract.response.Response com.sportswin.soa.spark.controller.ISparkGameUserController.sparkGameUserFirstVote(com.sportswin.soa.spark.contract.request.vote.SparkGameUserVoteRequest)
to {POST /spark/game/user/vote/first}: There is already 'sparkGameUserController' bean method
public com.sportswin.soa.misc.contract.response.Response com.sportswin.soa.spark.controller.impl.SparkGameUserController.sparkGameUserFirstVote(com.sportswin.soa.spark.contract.request.vote.SparkGameUserVoteRequest) mapped.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1340) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1186) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
```

I check the code, and did not found the Controller two method define with the same path. this is the rest controller method define:

```
    @GetMapping("/vote/first/{gameId}")
    Response<List<SparkGameUserVoteFirstResponse>> queryFirstVoteSparkGameUser(@PathVariable(value = "gameId") Long gameId);

    @PostMapping("/vote/first")
    Response sparkGameUserFirstVote(@RequestBody  @Valid SparkGameUserVoteRequest request);
```

why did this happen? what should I do to fix it?I feel like the controller initial twice.

Comment: You might try to add a debug or a logger to this controller constructor and verify that you are initializing it once. Secondly check for all RestMappings and verify there are no duplications. Could you also post controller class def with annotations?

Answer (score 1):

Try running a global text searching on text "/vote/first"? (Based on error msg you may have an api prefix "/spark/game/user" on this controller. Maybe somewhere else also produce the contacted api "/spark/game/user/vote/first")